# search and replace by instances. replace the first 10 1s with a 2 and the second 10 1s with a 3

Tags: python

I have a code in python to search and replace what I need though is to replace the first 10 instances of the number 1 with 2 and the second 10 instances with the number 3. Does anybody knows how to do that?

```
fin = open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt')
fout = open(r'F:\1\xxx2.txt', "wt")
for line in fin:
fout.write( line.replace('1', '2') )
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: You'll need to keep track of how many times '1' has been replaced.  This code doesn't even try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach should work:

```
# read file into string
with open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.read()
# get a list of all instances of number 1
all_index = [i for i,x in enumerate(lines) if x == '1']
# convert the file string into a list
list_lines = list(lines)
# replace the first 10 instances with 2;
# then the second 10 instances with 3
for i in all_index[:10]:
    list_lines[i] = '2' 
for i in all_index[10:20]:
    list_lines[i] = '3'
# write the resulting string into output file   
with open(r'F:\1\xxx2.txt','w') as fout:
    fout.write(''.join(list_lines))
```

Comment: sorry for being a hassle. but how would i do this in the case of a string and not a number? like if wanting to replace first 10 instances of x1 with x2 and the second 10 instances of x1 with x3.

Comment: @chickflick91: In this case, we just need to make sure `x` occurs before 1 when retrieving all the indexes, e.g. `all_index = [i for i,_ in enumerate(lines) if i != 0 and lines[i-1:i+1] == 'x1']`. Hope this helps.

Comment: great! almost there. its just that it works with string 'x1' but for some reason doesn't work if i use a longer string like 'stop1'. what am i missing?

Comment: Actually you can create a function (e.g. lambda): `get_all_index = lambda s : [i for i,_ in enumerate(lines) if i-len(s)+1 >= 0 and lines[i-len(s)+1:i+1] == s]`; then just call it this way: `all_index = get_all_index('stop1')`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we can write a function like this

```
i=-1
def repl(m):
  global i
  i+=1
  return str(i/10 + 2)
```

Your fout can be as below

```
fout.write(re.sub("1", repl, text))
```

As mentioned in the comments keeps count of the number of 1's encountered. Reset i=-1 when ever you need to reset the count.Like after writing each line etc. But make sure that i is declared global.